# Update join table using list of checkboxes in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, join, active-record

I have `Gig` and `Singer` Active Record models (standard--no customization just yet) with a many-to-many relationship through a generic join table which holds nothing but the respective ids of `Gig` and `Singer`.  My form sends a given gig id and all the singers who will be attending, denoted with check boxes.  I need to have the ability to check or uncheck singers.  The following code works, but it does so by removing all the singers from a gig and re-adding them.  This feels hacky... is there a better way?  (I think this is all the code necessary but let me know if you need me to add anything)

```
class GigSingersController < ApplicationController

    def create
        gig = Gig.find(params[:gig_id])
        singer_ids = params[:singer_ids] # [1, 4, 5,]
        gig.singers = []
        singer_ids.each do |id|
            singer = Singer.find(id)
            gig.singers << singer
        end
        redirect_to gigs_path
    end
end
```

EDIT:

As requested in the comments, here are the schema and relevant models, although as I said, they are completely generic.  Perhaps I didn't do a good job of making my question clear:  **Is the best way to create these relationships when using a checkbox to remove all existing ones and recreate them from the boxes currently checked, thereby removing any that the user *unchecked* on an edit?**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_07_19_195106) do

  create_table "gig_singers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "gig_id"
    t.integer "singer_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "gigs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "notes"
    t.datetime "datetime"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "singers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "active"
  end

class Gig < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :gig_singers
    has_many :singers, through: :gig_singers
end

class GigSinger < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :gig
    belongs_to :singer
end

class Singer < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :gig_singers
    has_many :gigs, through: :gig_singers

end
```

Comment: These are [tag:active-record] models?

Comment: On database questions, it's customary to provide a database schema. This allows us to see exactly how you store your data and the inefficiencies in the code used to retrieve data from it. Please consider adding those.

Comment: The current code is simply too small a part of what you're doing to say anything sensible about it.

Comment: @Mast It's not a database question.  I will include the things you are asking for but I can't see how they will possibly be of any help to the question I've asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, Active Record can work with joined collection (including has_many :through) from the box.

So, you just need to pass new collection instead of old, and AR will delete excessive and add new records.

In your code, need to change `create` method body to:

```
gig = Gig.find(params[:gig_id])
singer_ids = params[:singer_ids] # [1, 4, 5,]
gig.singers = Singer.find(singer_ids)
redirect_to gigs_path
```